# Django not updating SQLite tables properly

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I've been working on a project that involves an authentication page using Django and AngularJS. I have created an extended version of the User class and have added "company" and "phone_number" as fields.

Here's my code for models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator




class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
       if not email:
           raise ValueError('Users must have a valid email address')

       #if not kwargs.get('username'):
           #raise ValueError('Users must have a valid username')

       #if access_code not in ['password']:
           #raise ValueError('Sorry you are not eligible to join')

       account = self.model(
           email=self.normalize_email(email))

       account.set_password(password)
       account.save()

       return account

   def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
       account = self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)

       account.is_admin = True
       account.save()

       return account


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
   company = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
   phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
   phone_number = models.IntegerField(validators=[phone_regex], blank=False, null=True)  # validators should be a list
   # access_code = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, default='SOME STRING')

   is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   objects = AccountManager()

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'company', 'phone_number']

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.email

   def get_full_name(self):
       return ' '.join([self.first_name, self.last_name])

   def get_short_name(self):
       return self.first_name
```

Now when I go to terminal and perform python manage.py createsuperuser all the field options pop up for me to enter text. However when I check the database afterwards, only the email and password fields are updated. Company, phone number, first name, and last name return as ' '.

Any clue what I am doing wrong? I've been spending too much time trying to fix this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `create_user`, you haven't passed any of the other arguments to the `self.model` call, so you only set the email and, later, the password. You need to pass the kwargs in there too.

```
  account = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **kwargs)
```